# Adding multiple recipents EWS API

Tags: python, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send a simple email message to multiple recipients using EWS API via Python but I can't send to more than single address at a time.

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("C:\\Microsoft\\Exchange\\Web Services\\2.1\\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
from Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data import *

def main():

ex_service = ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)
ex_service.UseDefaultCredentials = True
ex_service.AutodiscoverUrl("me@companycom", redirect_url_validation_callback)
email = EmailMessage(ex_service)
email.ToRecipients.Add('r1@company.com')
email.Subject = "New TIP Report"
email.Body = '''A new TIP report has been published. 
Please visit https://google.com and login to complete the form.'''
    email.Send()

def redirect_url_validation_callback(redirect_url):
    redirect_uri = Uri(redirect_url)
    return redirect_uri.Scheme == "https"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I read that I need to Mime Content properties, but I was not able to succeed. Any clue how to add multiple recipients using EWS API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new line

```
email.ToRecipients.Add('r1@company.com')
```